Criteria for essential singularities
Pretty straight-forward question.
Wikipedia states the following criteria for a point in the complex plane to be an essential singularity for a complex function:
"If neither $\lim_{z \to a}f(z)$ nor $\lim_{z \to a}\frac{1}{f(z)}$, then $a$ is an essential singularity for both $f$ and $1/f$"
That seems quite strong,and there is no direct citations whatsoever to justify it.
Is this actually true? If so, it'll be useful for me. Thanks in advance.

I guess you mean "neither limit exists". And yes this is true, you can see that from Casorati-Weierstrass' theorem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem

Are you aware that there are only three types of isolated singularities (removable, pole, essential)? If $\lim_{z \to a}f(z)$ does not exist then it is not a removable singularity, and if $\lim_{z \to a}\frac{1}{f(z)}$ does exist then it is not a pole.

@MartinR For $f(z)=z^{-1}$ $\lim_{z\to 0}{1\over f(z)}=0$ and $0$ is a pole.

@RyszardSzwarc you appear to be responding to a typo in Martin R's comment. Martin certainly meant "...does not exist then it is not a pole".

@MartinR: if $\lim\limits_{z\to a}\frac1{f(z)}$ does not exist, then it is not a pole.

Yes, that is what I meant to say.
